# Merely chainloading an Acer Recovery Partition deleted all data

Tags: windows, data-recovery, acer-aspire, partition-recovery

I was starting a backup of Acer's factory restore partition located inside of an extended partition to determine whether or not it still worked.  I clicked "take no action" once I saw that it had, in fact, successfully started up.  However, when I rebooted, I got an "error: no such partition" and was dropped to a GRUB recovery prompt.

Upon further investigation, I discovered that all partitions inside the extended partition were gone except for the recovery partition!

[image: What GParted sees when looking at the disk layout]

What happened?  How can I fix this?  `testdisk` doesn't find the deleted partitions!

Comment: Since this is practically a bug report, anyone who wishes to vote to close may do so.  I can't decide.

Comment: Alright, close! Hehe, just kidding. Actually this is a serious, legitimate question. It is indeed a possible bug report, but you are also asking how to recover your partition, which is not a bug report. From your description, it sounds like the recovery programs is seriously buggy if it made changes (and destructive ones no less) when it shouldn’t have.

Comment: Okay!  Thanks for the closure.  (That was necessary :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `testdisk` to recover the partitions.  This took a *long* time, and I asked a question about it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/524140/start-testdisk-from-specific-point-or-sector).

Comment: `I ended up using testdisk to recover the partitions. This took a long time`   I can imagine. This is one of the downsides of larger disks; data-recovery is infeasible. ಠ_ಠ