# Start testdisk from specific point or sector

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

Recently, a malfunctioning program cleared all but one partition entries inside of an extended partition.  I was going to just run a deep search with testdisk, but by my calculations, this will take anywhere from seven to thirteen hours to complete (slow 1TB drive).

Is there a parameter I can run testdisk with to tell it to start from, say, halfway through my hard  disk?

Comment: I did finish the scan the long way, but I would still like to know if this is possible.

Comment: `Is there a parameter I can run testdisk with to tell it to start from, say, halfway through my hard disk?`   Hmm, I should think there would be, but I can’t find it, even when enabling *Expert Mode*. I know that PhotoRec lets you select to only search free clusters (and can find lost file-system structures for FAT), but TestDisk seems to not support the controls and signatures needed to simplify this. I’m sure I’ve seen some other programs that let you specify a starting sector, but I think they could only find *files* (by signature), not partitions.